# Pseudo constants that very rarely need to change on runtime in a web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, conventions

So I'm asking the question in the context of Rails, although it shouldn't really matter.

On my web app I have something like a monthly subscription fees and other prices that is right now hard coded as a constant in a class.

However, the person managing the site will want to be fiddling with the prices and numbers once in a while, and it doesn't seem right that he has to go into the code, change it, push it to the server etc.

So I guess you store it in the database as a single row in a constants table.. but I don't know.. Is this the right way of going about it? What does public wisdom dictate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much you trust the person running the site.

However, in the case of subscription fees, I recommend a plans table so that you can 'grandfather' people to old plans when you change the price, as well as give different price options, and even track history and plan changes for a given customer. Think of it like accounting - you want as much information in the database as possible.

For other constants, it depends how often you're changing them and what they're for, and how much you trust the person running the site to not break things (does the site have tests and CI?).

Answer (score 1):

I think thats ok. An alternative would be using environment variables...